# i dont know what to do with loops and if statements

Tags: loops

Write a subroutine that outputs the numbers from 1 to X. For the multiples of three output “Fizz” instead of the number and for the multiples of five output “Buzz”. For numbers which are multiples of both three and five output “FizzBuzz”.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried and tell us what is not working

Comment: I'd start here: https://www.tomdalling.com/blog/software-design/fizzbuzz-in-too-much-detail

Comment: Do you know how to check if a number is a multiple of another number?

Comment: Sounds like you're just forwarding your own assignment in entirety. Try adding what have you tried so far